# Regex for splitting Markdown (Android)

Tags: java, android, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

So I have some text in MarkDown which I'd like to split between headers into a string array, but including the content between the headers.
So for the following example:

```
**Header 1**Lots of text here.\n**Header 2**More and more text here..\n**Header 3** etc..
```

What I'd like to end up with is an array of:

```
**Header 1**Lots of text here.\n
**Header 2**More and more text here..\n
**Header 3** etc..
```

What I'm trying is along the lines of (?<=\*{1,10}.*\*{1,10}) although I think somewhere in there should be something like [^*{2}] to include every char but only a max of 2 *'s (the close of the header).
The \n is not guaranteed to be before the header so I'm a little bit stumped about how to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: is your string having `\n`

Comment: It does atm but it's not guaranteed

Comment: I use http://rubular.com/ for testing regex on the fly. With this site, it's very easy to debug regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this lookaheads based regex for matching:

```
((?:\*\*.+?(?=\*\*|$)){2,})
```

- `(?=\*\*|$)` is positive lookahead assertion to match any text until we hit a `\*\*` or end of line.
- Range of `{2,}` will ensure at least two `**` in matched text
- Captured group #1 will you the text you're interested in

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qY5zP6/2)

Comment: I appreciate the response buddy but the issue with that is the header in between the astrerisks can be any text, header was just an example of header text

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

(*{2}.+?*{2}.*?)(?=*{2}|$)/gi

It gets everything between 2 pairs of ** and the text following it until finding another ** or an end of line. It's important to keep the $ condition to catch the last group (When you don't have any **header** left).

Demo: 
https://regex101.com/r/fI0gV6/4

Comment: Appreciate the response buddy and that does exactly what I want it to, except, the header in between the astrerisks can be any text, header was just an example of header text

Comment: In that case I will change a bit the way of matching. Now it should catch whatever text you want to use instead of "header".